# .NET MAUI Blazor: Cannot display PDF files as bytes array in object element

Tags: html, iframe, blazor, hybrid, .net-maui

I have a PDF file as a bytes array and I want to display it into **<object** element in .NET MAUI hybrid application.
I tried it on windows and it works fine, but on Android it doesn't work, it shows blank white content. I didn't try on iOS because it doesn't available for me right now.

I tried to display the PDF file from URL in **<iframe** but it also works on Windows only, but it shows blank content on android

My code:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;padding:10px;">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:600px;" src="@bookPath"></iframe>
</div>
<div style="border:1px solid orange;padding:10px;">
    <object data="@bytesText" width="900" height="600" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>

@code{
    string bytesText = string.Empty;
    private string bookPath= "https://my-url/book_1.pdf";
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      var bytes = await (await Http.GetStreamAsync("api/book/bytes")).ToByteArrayAsync();
      bytesText = $"data:application/pdf;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}";

    }
}
```

So, any ideas about this problem?
Thank you

Comment: I have read your question and may I know the file type of bytestext you want to transfer. By the way, what does object element and iframe mean?

Comment: @HongxinSui What do you mean by file type? I have mentioned that the file is PDF, is that what you mean?

Comment: @HongxinSui object & iframe are HTML elements

Comment: The Android platform may not support full display of PDF files, PDF files may only be opened in the browser.